# How to change SFSafariViewController ToolBar color

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, uitoolbar, sfsafariviewcontroller

Expected Output:
I want to change the ToolBar color to Dark Black.

Actual Output:
ToolBar is light Grey color.

Here is the code:

```
let webViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: So what happens. Is your code not working or what ? Please add more details.

Comment: @Mack Tool Bar Code is not taking impact on SFSafariViewController Bottom.

Comment: you try to set tintcolor ?

Comment: @BlackbirdSR-71 self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() i already did. but it is not taking any impact

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Updated Answer for iOS 10 API**

`SFSafariViewController` now has `preferredBarTintColor` and `preferredControlTintColor` properties to control how the toolbars look.

---

**Original Answer**

`SFSafariViewController` renders off-process. You can only change the tint color, but not bar style or bar tint color.

To set the tint color, set the Safari controller's view's tint color like so:

```
let sfController = SFSafariViewController(URL: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
sfController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
navigationController?.showViewController(sfController, sender: self)
```

Comment: i was able to change the color of navigation bar. But my client req is to change the color of toolbar.

Comment: @Audi It's not possible. Open an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: or you can use wkwebview and make your own toolbar

Comment: Make sure that you're not setting the tint for the window or for all views using `appearance` somewhere else or this won't work.

Comment: Tried the preferred properties and didn't work. Tried removing all calls to `appearance` and still does not work.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways:

```
let resetPasswordSafari = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
resetPasswordSafari.preferredBarTintColor = .mainColor
resetPasswordSafari.preferredControlTintColor = .black
```

And:

```
class ResetPasswordSafariViewController: SFSafariViewController {

  override init(url URL: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: Bool) {
    super.init(url: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: entersReaderIfAvailable)
    delegate = self

    preferredBarTintColor = .blue
    preferredControlTintColor = .black
  }
}

// MARK: - SFSafariViewControllerDelegate

extension ResetPasswordSafariViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
  internal func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
  }
}
```

Good luck all!

Comment: what's `internal func safariViewControllerDidFinish` for?

and will apple approve apps that subclass `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: @spnkr yes, will approve. Here's the definition of "internal" access level:

Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.

Answer (score 1):

//To make changes in SFSafariViewController

```
     if let url = URL(string:"https://sandydhumale.business.site") {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
        config.barCollapsingEnabled = true
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
        vc.dismissButtonStyle = .close
        vc.preferredBarTintColor = .green // Your choice color
        vc.preferredControlTintColor = .white // All buttons/items color
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to change background color of ToolBar, but it is possible to change color of buttons in ToolBar.

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

All other changes in appearance, or directly in controller properties, have no effect, as I see.